# When I refresh the page after login+redirect, it redirects me to login page again

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, servlet-filters

Good Day!

Im having a problem with my log in in JSF, it seems that after the log in, the session becomes null. It logs me in the first, but when i hit refresh or go to another page it redirects to login. Hope anybody can help with this. Below are my codes.

Thanks

Filter Class:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
        FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = (session != null) ? (User) session.getAttribute("userBean") : null;

    if(user != null){
        arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
    }else{
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Login from User Managed Bean Class:

```
public void login(){
    UserDAO action = new UserDAO();

    try{
        User u = action.login(username, password);

        if(u == null){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(showLogin() + ".xhtml?ref=err");
        }else{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);                           
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userBean", u);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("pages/dashboard.xhtml");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>rpt.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you look with the debugger at the value in the location of the redirect? It should contain the `/pages` pattern.

Comment: which redirect are you talking about?thanks

Comment: This one: `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");`

Comment: `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` makes me uncomfortable. You realize that means that regardless of authentication, a session will always be created?